# Hostapd: is possible to reach a better speed?

Tags: hostapd

My nmcli report those speed on wifi routers

```
nmcli device wifi list
Wufr1                   Infra  44    270 Mbit/s  36      ▂▄__  WPA2 WPA3    
other                   Infra  11    270 Mbit/s  40      ▂▄__  WPA2
other                   Infra  12    540 Mbit/s  37      ▂▄__  WPA2
other                   Infra  2     540 Mbit/s  30      ▂___  WPA2
other                   Infra  6     540 Mbit/s  30      ▂___  WPA2
```

the "Wufr1" is my AP with hostapd, why is limited to 270MB? Is possible to reach 540mb?
This is my hostapd.conf

```
interface=wlan1
bridge=br0
driver=nl80211
ssid=Wufr1
hw_mode=a
channel=36
ieee80211d=1
ieee80211n=1
ieee80211ac=1
wmm_enabled=1
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
country_code=IT
macaddr_acl=1
accept_mac_file=/etc/hostapd/hostapd.accept

# WPA
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=forget
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK SAE
wpa_pairwise=CCMP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
sae_password=forget
wps_cred_add_sae=1
ieee80211w=2
own_ip_addr=127.0.0.1

#HT
require_ht=1
require_vht=1

ht_capab=[HT40+][SHORT-GI-40][MAX-AMSDU-3839]
```

This is the driver.conf for server

```
options 88x2bu rtw_drv_log_level=0 rtw_led_ctrl=0 rtw_vht_enable=2 rtw_power_mgnt=1 rtw_beamform_cap=0 rtw_dfs_region_domain=1 rtw_switch_usb_mode=1
```

and client

```
options 88x2bu rtw_drv_log_level=0 rtw_led_ctrl=0
```

The connection is stable, but speed is very slow
For example using rsync

machine3 can get 10MB/s (very poor)

machine1 can upload to machine3 at..5MB/s (awful)

Any advice? Thanks